# Debugging compiler error in ngfactory file

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build my Angular 2 app, using `ng build --prod`. The error started after upgrading to angular-cli 1.0.0. I'm using angular 2.3.1.

The build is failing with an error:

> ....filters.component.ngfactory.ts (975,35): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

**My question is: given that all the interim files get deleted when the compilation fails, how can I use the compiler error (`ngfactory` line 975) to identify the problem in my source code?**

**Update:** JB Nizet found the bug in the code below (now edited to make it easier for later readers to see the error), but my question still stands regarding how to make use of the debugging info from the compiler.

Here is my component

```
     getFavourites() {
        this.overlay = false;
        // this.router.navigate(['/recommendations', 'close']);
        this.action.emit({
            type: GET_FAVOURITES
        });
    }


}
```

and the template

```
            <button class='afbutton hidden-xs' (click)='getFavourites($event)'>
                <span class="icon">
                    <svg class="favourite heart" viewBox="0 0 32 29.6">
                    <path d="M23.6,0c-3.4,0-6.3,2.7-7.6,5.6C14.7,2.7,11.8,0,8.4,0C3.8,0,0,3.8,0,8.4c0,9.4,9.5,11.9,16,21.2
                c6.1-9.3,16-12.1,16-21.2C32,3.8,28.2,0,23.6,0z" /></svg>
                </span>
                favourites
            </button>
```

Comment: More context would help, what it sounds like is that you want to call some method and provide it with the wrong inputs. Maybe provide a plunker with  the code?

Comment: Post the code of filters.component.ts, and of its template.

Comment: I've added more code - hopefully that helps. This is super frustrating as it worked before the upgrade and angular-cli

Comment: Add your html as well

Comment: You're calling getFavourites($event) from your template, but getFavourites() doesn't have any argument. I stopped reading there.

Comment: Hey, my name is Nizet, not Nezbit :-)

Comment: When i was upgrading my project to support angular v4 and angular-cli v1 i encountered a large number of such errors :)

Comment: You open filters.component.ngfactory.ts and check what's wrong at (975,35) position. It is always as simple as that - as long as you've got ngfactory file generated, because it's not always so.

Comment: @estus the question is precisely: how to get access to the generated filters.component.ngfactory.ts file?

Comment: Why the down vote? I have seen several other people on SO also struggling to track down similar errors

Comment: It was probably downvoted because it wasn't clear why you can't check ngfactory file by yourself. Now it is. A repo that can replicate the problem would probably help as well.

Comment: that's weird as in bold I have **given that all the interim files get deleted when the compilation fails**

Answer (score 1):

Optionally add a genDir to your src/tsconfig.app.json so that the files are generated out-of-source.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "genDir": "aot"
}
```

Then just run ngc `./node_modules/.bin/ngc --project src/tsconfig.app.json` to produce the intermediate `ngfactory.ts` files, e.g. my error was in `src/aot/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts`.

Found under [Compiling the application](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#compile-with-aot).

I did not found any options to preserve the intermediate files with angular-cli (`ng build`).

Comment: Annoyingly, this points to some incompatibility with ng-animation `Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'NoOpAnimationDriver', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AnimationDriver.NOOP`